# How do you set multiple clauses for dataframe loc()?

Tags: python, pandas

I’m trying to create a new dataframe by grabbing certain rows from another df by setting a couple conditions in the df.loc()

```py
df2 = df.loc[((df.CustID == i) & (df['Section'].isin(['group1', 'group2']))),
                    ['CustID', 'Section']].copy()
```

But I’m getting sections that aren’t group1 or group2 so I’m a bit confused on what I’m doing wrong.

I’ve tried separating into an additional dataframe, but there has to be a way to accomplish it without adding the extra df.

Comment: Did you read [indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html)

Comment: also provide sample data/code (as dataframe) and show what you get and what you expect to get as output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your line of code it looks like you are missing `]` try the below code or else help us with the data sample to guide you better.

Also single `&` would work

```py
df2 = df.loc[(df.CustID == i) & (df['Section'].isin(['group1', 'group2'])), ['CustID', 'Section']].copy()
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. 
Unfortunately it was just a typo on here but I edited the post to fix it.

Comment: If the above code still doesn't help, please share any sample data to assess better